# Flutter plugins not installed

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies, mobile-development

I have installed both flutter and **Dart** plugins on **Android Studio** but when I run **flutter** doctor, it shows that plugins are not installed

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√]
 Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1139], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.51.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: restart your android studio and check again. if its dose not work try to re install both plugins

Comment: tried both and the issue is still there

Comment: the thing is if i run flutter doctor then the same problem is in my computer too but everything is working fine and there is no problem with my flutter development .

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still having this issue on `Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2`, running on Mac using Apple M1 Chip, the command should be `ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio2021.1`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem check: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/4523

If you are on Mac: `ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.1`

For windows and/or Linux you can try Flutter Dev channel:

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: upgraded flutter but the issue is still on :(